# From []byte to char*

Tags: c, pointers, go, cgo

I want to wrap a C function that takes a `char*` pointing to (the first element of) a non-empty buffer of bytes. I'm trying to wrap that in a Go function using CGo so that I can pass it a `[]byte`, but I don't know how to do the conversion. A simplified version of the C function's signature is

```
void foo(char const *buf, size_t n);
```

I tried passing a pointer to the first `byte` in the slice with

```
C.foo(&b[0], C.size_t(n))
```

That doesn't compile, though:

```
cannot use &b[0] (type *byte) as type *_Ctype_char in function argument
```

So what's the correct procedure here? The [go-wiki](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo) only describes the reverse situation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, that turned out to be much easier than I thought:

```
(*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))
```

does the trick. (Found this at [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/f1sWP3-YbuI).)