# How should I use the GetDIBits function

Tags: go, winapi

```
var bitmap win.BITMAP
win.GetObject(win.HGDIOBJ(hBitmap), unsafe.Sizeof(bitmap), unsafe.Pointer(&bitmap))
var bmpInfo win.BITMAPINFO
bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(Info.BmiHeader))
....................Width = width
....................Height = height
....................Planes = 1
....................BitCount = 24
....................Compression = win.BI_RGB
var hdc win.HDC
hdc = win.GetDC(0)
win.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, uint32(bitmap.BmHeight), bitmapInfo, nil, 0)
pBits := make([]byte, imageSize)
win.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, uint32(bitmap.BmHeight), bitmapInfo, (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&pBits)), 0)
```

use package `github.com/lxn/win`

First of all, we have done all the work before getting the GetDIBits function.

After that, I finally try to get the image data using the GetDIBits function, but it keeps returning 0.

I changed the data type of pBits to 'unsafe.Pointer' or '* byte' and tried it but it returned nil or 0.

How can I get the image data from the GetDIBits function?

Comment: Guessing you are using ```github.com/lxn/win``` (please specify packages used to avoid guesswork). In that case try passing ```&pBits[0]``` into the function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375997/from-byte-to-char) for more info).

Comment: @Brits The package is specified in the text.
And I tried it the way you told me, so the value is 0.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question; unfortunately any further suggestions would be guesswork without further info. Are you able to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I agree with Brits, you may first provide a example for our test.And if you are interested, here is a silmilar C++ [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313903/using-getdibits-to-load-a-bitmap) for your reference.

Comment: @Brits Updated contents!!

Comment: @SangGeol The parameters of GetDIBits seem incorrect, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Go language, but when you use `GetDIBits`, the position of parameters is incorrect.

> **lpvBits**
>
> A pointer to a buffer to receive the bitmap data. If this parameter is
>   NULL, the function passes the dimensions and format of the bitmap to
>   the BITMAPINFO structure pointed to by the lpbi parameter.
>
> **lpbmi**
>
> A pointer to a BITMAPINFO structure that specifies the desired format
>   for the DIB data.

You can modify it like this:

```
win.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, uint32(bitmap.BmHeight), nil, bitmapInfo, 0)
pBits := make([]byte, imageSize)

win.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, uint32(bitmap.BmHeight), (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&pBits)), bitmapInfo, 0)
```

Refer: [Using GetDIBits to load a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313903/using-getdibits-to-load-a-bitmap)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer. The signature of the function is ```func GetDIBits(hdc HDC, hbmp HBITMAP, uStartScan uint32, cScanLines uint32, lpvBits *byte, lpbi *BITMAPINFO, uUsage uint32) int32``` so ```uUsage``` (becomes ```usage``` in the winapi call) is an integer (which can be 0 but not null) and the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits) say that [```DIB_RGB_COLORS```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/a5e722e3-891a-4a67-be1a-ed5a48a7fda1) = ```0x00``` so that looks correct?